# How to stop voice recognition during tts speaking?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am making an application that uses both voice recognition and tts.
In my application I have continues voice recognition, the problem is that when I use tts the voice recognition will listen for what the app said. How can I stop the voice recognition during the time tts is speaking and then start it after the tts finishes? Can I solve the problem in another way?

Comment: Common sense dictates you should stop speech recognition while tts is busy. Perhaps you could shed some light on the code you're using to start speech recognition? Otherwise, I'm afraid no one will be able to answer this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `OnUtteranceCompletedListener` or `UtteranceProgressListener` and call `startListening` in `onUtteranceCompleted` or `onDone`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have found several tutorials showing how to do that, but it isn't working, maybe I am using it in a wrong way.

Comment: Just post your code that did not work. You have to pass in an utteranceId when calling speak for onUtteranceCompleted or onDone to be called.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it with an Asynctask

But I can't launch the voice recognition now.

```
private class MiTareaAsincronaDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        String words = "Esto es una prueba del texto pasado a oral";
        speakWords(words);
        while(myTTS.isSpeaking() == true)
        {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea finalizada!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() 
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea cancelada!",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```